# Firebase information are showing in one list item of the ListView

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-arrayadapter

This is my code its showing all of the information that are returned from the Fire-base that the app is connected to in one item of the list view.

can some one please help with the code.

```
public class usernews extends AppCompatActivity {
    FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    final DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference("allNews");
    private ListView lsStudents;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_usernews);
        lsStudents=(ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

I think that the error is some where here but I can't find it

```
myRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        // This method is called once with the initial value and again
        // whenever data at this location is updated.

        final List<String> areas = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (DataSnapshot areaSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            String value1 = String.valueOf(dataSnapshot.getValue());
            areas.add(value1);
        }

        String value2 = String.valueOf(dataSnapshot.getValue());
        Log.d("allNews", "Value is: " + value2);

        ArrayAdapter<String> areasAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(usernews.this,android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_1, areas);
        lsStudents.setAdapter(areasAdapter);
    }
});
```

Screenshot of Firebase data. [Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6qHF3.png)

Screenshot after referring correct node [Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GYDAS.png)

Comment: Can you show your Firebase data's node structure

Comment: Add screenshot of your node structure

Comment: i'v add a link for the image above

Comment: Any error messages? Log entries? Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @rahulkapoor: please ask for *screenshots* of the data structure as JSON text, instead of screenshots (as screenshots are unusable in an answer without having to type the data again). The best way to get the data structure is as plain JSON text, which OP can get by clicking the Export JSON link in the Firebase Database console.

Comment: Agree frank, I will keep that in my mind. Thank you for pointing that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your `DataBaseReference`.

Use this

```
final DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference("allNews").child("allNews");
```

Instead of

```
final DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference("allNews");
```

Your actual data is inside of `"allNews"` tag. Eventually its child node also have same name.

And then update your for-loop. You are getting data from wrong reference.

```
final List<String> areas = new ArrayList<String>();
for (DataSnapshot areaSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
    // Get value from areaSnapShot not from dataSnapshot
    String value1 = String.valueOf(areaSnapshot.getValue());
    areas.add(value1);
}
```

Comment: i changed it but its still giving me many list items but all of them have all the firebase information.

Comment: What response you are getting, what do you mean by all firebase information

Comment: i added another  link you can check it

Comment: thanks a lot  man your a life saver it worked properly at last  thank you